# How can I drag the mouse across multiple inputs or elements with contentEditable to select the text inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When contentEditable is set to true, only the element that is focused can be selected. I'm trying to make cells that function like they do in excel. I'd like to be able to edit the cell on a single click, otherwise I would just set contentEditable with state and select them as regular div elements. I thought about doing something with onMouseOut to change the state to false, but thet doesn't seem to work.

App component:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Cell from "./Cell";

export default function App() {
  const testRef = useRef();
  const [st, setSt] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (st) testRef.current.focus();
  }, [st]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Cell tabindex="1" />
      <Cell tabindex="2" />
      <Cell tabindex="3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cell component:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Cell() {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(true);

  const testRef = useRef();

  const stopEditing = () => setEditing(false);
  const startEditing = () => setEditing(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={testRef}
        contentEditable={editing}
        // onBlur={stopEditing}
        // onMouseUp={stopEditing}
        onMouseOver={startEditing}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          border: "1px solid #696969",
          width: "100px",
          height: "25px",
          cursor: "cell",
          margin: "2px"
        }}
      ></div>
      <p>{editing.toString()}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-rain-i0v40g?file=/src/Cell.js:0-734

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You want to select the entire row or select multiple cells with shift + click?

Comment: I want to drag the mouse across multiple cells to select them

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "div1" onmousedown = "selectFunction()"> 

function selectFunction() { 

document.getElementByClassName("div1")[0].style.color = "red"; }
```

Maybe something like this? However, this will only work for one of the div's, try applying them to all the div's. This might not work, I'll edit it if it does not. (All this does it highlight the div red, probably won't work if you want to select multiple div's at once)

Comment: Won't work, I'm trying to select multiple cells for copy pasting purposes. In my actual code I'm using a table, this sandbox was just for testing purposes. But yeah, I want to recreate the way you would edit/copy/paste on excel or google sheets.

Comment: Ah alright sorry about that

Comment: no worries, actually does help with another thing I would have to figure out eventually, so  that's good.

Comment: Alright nice, glad to hear that I helped in some way (: